# Spliting a String upto nth delimiter in java

Tags: java, regex, split

```
String s = "10.226.18.158:10.226.17.183:ABCD :AAAA"
```

My requirement is to split the string at up to 3rd `:` or up to 2nd `:`. i.e.

Something like `String sa[] = s.split()`, but with the regex splitting only up to 3rd or 2nd.

```
s[0] = "10.226.18.158"
s[1] = "10.226.17.183"
s[2] = "ABCD :AAAA"
```

Comment: Just split it and concatenate the remaining elements after element 0 and 1?

Comment: Looks like you are splitting up sets of IP addresses, mixed IPv4 and IPv6? Do you also just need it for this string, or is there a pattern which looks like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [String#split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) javadoc you can add a number to limit the number of splits.

```
s.split(":", 3);
```

**Edit:** as melwil metions This will return an array of up to the number passed in long.

So in your example of splitting up to 2nd `:` you would need to pass in 3.

`s.split(":",3)` returns the output

```
sa[0] = "10.226.18.158"
sa[1] = "10.226.17.183"
sa[2] = "ABCD :AAAA"
```

Relevent section quoted from the java doc about how the second argument (limit) works.

> The limit parameter controls the number of times the pattern is
>   applied and therefore affects the length of the resulting array. If
>   the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at
>   most n - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and
>   the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched
>   delimiter. If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as
>   many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero
>   then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array
>   can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Comment: It may be prudent to point out that the split does not happen up to Nth delimiter, but rather limits the resulting array to a length of N. In `s.split(":", 3);`, it will split up to 2nd delimiter, resulting in an array of size 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your string basing on one non-whitespece character, `\S{1}`, followed by a colon, `:`:

```
String sa[] = s.split("\\S{1}:");
```